# Conversion of Standard Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

Convert the standard Linear Programming where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$
$$\min \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}\\
s.t\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}\\
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mathbf{x}\geq 0 $$
The question wants to convert the above LP in the form of 
$$\min \mathbf{d}^T\mathbf{y}\\
s.t.\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mathbf{Gy}\leq \mathbf{h}\\
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$$
where $\mathbf{G,h,d}$ should be expressed in terms of $\mathbf{A,b,c}$. Could someone enlighten me how to start?
I am thinking along the line of converting back to auxilliary LP but it does not work.

Comment: I understand dual LP can solve it when $n\geq 2m$ but I am stuck with the case where $n<2m$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am well aware of that but the constraint is that $\mathbf{y}$ has $n-m$ dimensions which is fewer than $\mathbf{x}$, which has $n$.

Comment: Perhaps you could express $\{x | Ax = b \}$ as $\{x_0 + L y\}$?